# how to create GUI for embedded systems

Tags: gui, xserver, embedded-system

I need to create a GUI for a program that I will build to run in a minimal version of linux in an embedded system that i am making.

Not sure if I'm going with arm or small factor x86 architecture and maybe the answer to this post will help me decide.

I found altia (url: altia.com) but they dont provide the framework to personal projects.

Is there any other alternative, that I can use, to create a beautiful GUI for programs, oriented to low resources systems such embedded solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this specifically Ubuntu, or Linux in general?

Comment: Well I want to use ubuntu minimal instalation but I assume that most solutions will be distribution independent

Comment: This question may be better on the unix / linux stack exchange... But I won't flag it for moving as it is fine here I think, you just might get better answers over there.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly vague, but I'll go ahead and recommend GTK+ and Vala. Run a basic X.org instance with no shell or desktop environment and just your app. Of course, nothing prevents you from using Qt, HTML5, or anything else.

Comment: gonna give it a go to see if it is what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Went looking for this technology but it looks like Vala is just another language, right? I mean.. I could do the same with C, right?

So based on this assumption, the technology you are suggesting is GTK+, corret?

Also, how can I use HTML5 like suggested without a browser?

Comment: Right. You'd create a program that runs full-screen with nothing else. That's what you want, isn't it? It is very easy to use a WebKit WebView with Vala and GTK+ or another language; create a window, create a webview, add the webview to the window, open a page in the webview, connect wanted signals and show everything in the window. That question is probably asked and answered before, but if not, open a new one and link here, then I'll answer it in more detail.

Comment: THX mate. I think that's it. I'll search for more info on that. If i cant find i'll create the new question and link it here! Cheers